# How do I phrase this condition in T-SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table in `SQL Server 2012` with employees data. An extract is shown below:

```
 empID     DateOfEntry    DateLeft
  102      2015-05-21     2016-04-20
  104      2015-05-14     2015-12-28
  ...
```

I need to extract all employees who were present during the period `2016-07-01` and `2017-06-30`.

To do this, I need to add a `WHERE` filter on the `DateLeft` column in my query but I am a bit confused as to how to phrase this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
WHERE DateOfEntry <= '2017-06-30'
    and DateLeft >= '2016-07-01'
```

You can think of your question as "people who started before (or on) your latest date and left after (or on) your Earliest date".

Comment: Aren't we missing people who joined (DateOfentry) between 2016-07-01 and 2017-06-30 here?

Comment: Do you mean people with a NULL DateLeft?

Comment: I am sorry. I messed up. I thought 2016-07-01 was on the first line of your codes!

Comment: No worries.  :)  --(Exra chars for no reason)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [mytable]
WHERE [DateOfEntry] >= '2016-07-01'
   AND [DateLeft] <= '2017-06-30';
```

Also, when working with dates and ranges, do not use `BETWEEN` even some people are going to show you the syntax.

To be precise, you should avoid passing dates as string in this format, too:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

As it can break  under certain scenarios — such as when the user's language settings are set to French:

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
GO
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2009-10-13');
```

You can use `YYYYMMDD` instead.

Aaron Bertrand has nice [article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) about dates and dates ranges, part of his series - `Bad habits to kick` - you can find more details and examples there, if you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

**"all employees who were present during the period 2016-07-01 and 2017-06-30"**

Your phrasing implies several scenarios so I will address all

If you want employees who were present in these two dates specifically, use IN operator in your where filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM <Table>
WHERE DateLeft in ('2016-07-01','2017-06-30');
```

If you want employees who were present through these range of two dates you can use 
'between' syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM <Table>
WHERE DateLeft between '2017-06-30' and '2016-07-01';
```

*Note that when using 'between' begin and end values are included, so assuming you want to exclude the last date in range for example you will need to use greater then or equal / lower then operators*

```
SELECT *
FROM <Table>
WHERE DateLeft >= '2017-06-30' and DateLeft < '2016-07-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE(empID INT,DateOfEntry DATE,DateLeft DATE)
INSERT @Employee
SELECT 101,'2015-05-21','2016-08-20' UNION ALL -- O
SELECT 102,'2015-05-21','2016-04-20' UNION ALL -- X
SELECT 104,'2015-05-14','2015-12-28' UNION ALL -- X
SELECT 105,'2015-05-14','2018-12-28'            -- O

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2016-07-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2017-06-30'


SELECT * FROM @Employee 
WHERE 
(DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@StartDate) <=0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@EndDate) >= 0)
OR
(DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@StartDate) <=0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@EndDate) <= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution is also including people whose DateOfEntry is > 2017-06-30

Comment: Try this, SELECT * FROM @Employee 
WHERE 
(DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@StartDate) <=0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@EndDate) >= 0)
OR
(
 (DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@StartDate) <=0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,DateLeft,@EndDate) <= 0)
 AND
 DATEDIFF(DAY,DateOfEntry,@StartDate) > 0
)